# Does Thingsboard store telemetry data into database by default?

Tags: iot, thingsboard

I'm studying the ThingsBoard IoT platform and what's not clear to me is:

does ThingsBoard store **by default** its telemetry data into the configured database (Postgres or Cassandra) ?

I can also put the question in another way: when I view telemetry data from device's dashboard, where do those data come from?

What I understood is that the **default** data flow is:

device > transport layer (mqtt, http) > Kafka

so I think you must create an appropriate rule into the rule engine if you want to further save your telemetry data into your database, but I'm not sure about this, please correct me if i'm wrong.

Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer:

Telemetry data are not stored into database by default unless you configure a rule chain with the specific action to do so.

That being said, during ThingsBoard installation the Root rule chain is created for you, and it contains the actions to [save timeseries](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/action-nodes/#save-timeseries-node) and attributes into the configured database. The target tables where telemetry data are stored are **ts_kv_latest_cf** for latest telemetry data and **ts_kv_cf** for timeseries data.

If you want to do a quick and simple check, try to temporarily remove the 'save timeseries' rule node from the Root rule chain, and to send data into the platform.